# A boundedness condition on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We have maps $F:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ on a Banach space $X$.

Let $F(u,v) = f(u+v) - f(u-v)$. The map $f$ is nonlinear and not identically zero (to avoid trivial statements), and the map $F$ is bilinear.

Suppose we know that $|F(u,v)| \leq C|u|_X|v|_X$.

Is it always the case then that $$|f(u+v)| \leq C_1|u|_X|v|_X?$$

If not, I guess there is no way to tell when this condition always holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=x^2$$

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i phrased the question wrong. I will post another.

Comment: You are welcome @soup